# What is the proper definition for a constexpr function that take a character array?

Tags: c++, constexpr, user-defined-literals, constexpr-function

I'm writing a hashing function to help speed up string comparisons.
My codebase compares strings against a lot of `const char[]` constants, and it would be ideal if I could work with hashes instead. I went ahead and translated xxHash to modern C++, and I have a working prototype that does work at compile time, but I'm not sure what the function definition should be for the main hashing function.

At the moment, I have this:

```
template <size_t arr_size>
constexpr uint64_t xxHash64(const char(data)[arr_size])
{...}
```

This does work, and I am able to do a compile time call like this

```
constexpr char myString[] = "foobar";
constexpr uint64_t hashedString = xxHash64<sizeof myString>(myString);
```

[Find a minimal [example here](https://godbolt.org/z/foTdxMz77)]

All good so far, but I would like to add a user-defined literal wrapper function for some eye candy, and this is where the problem lies.
UDLs come with a fixed prototype, as [specified here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/user-defined-literals-cpp?view=msvc-170#user-defined-literal-operator-signatures)
The Microsoft doc stipulates "*Also, any of these operators can be defined as constexpr*".
But when I try to call my hashing function from a constexpr UDL:

```
constexpr uint64_t operator "" _hashed(const char *arr, size_t size) {
    return xxHash64<size>(arr);
}
```

> function "xxHash64" cannot be called with the given argument list
> argument types are: (const char*)

And the error does make sense. My function expects a character array, and instead it gets a pointer.
But if I were to modify the definition of my xxHash64 function to take a `const char *`, I can no longer work in a constexpr context because the compiler needs to resolve the pointer first, which happens at runtime.

So am I doing anything wrong here, or is this a limitation of UDLs or constexpr functions as a whole?
Again, I'm not 100% sure the templated definition at the top is the way to go, but I'm not sure how else I could read characters from a string at compile time.

I'm not limited by any compiler version or library. If there is a better way to do this, feel free to suggest.

Comment: did you forget a `&` somewhere maybe? The part you claim to be working does not compile https://godbolt.org/z/zs9KMGn7d. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: I think you want to pass the array by reference https://godbolt.org/z/zs9KMGn7d

Comment: and then  `return xxHash64<size>(arr);` wont work. `arr` is a pointer not an array

Comment: i think your issue boils down to: pointers are not array and arrays are not pointers.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Sorry about that. Updated my question with an example. You can also find it here https://godbolt.org/z/fvzdxTjEx

Comment: you can still call it with `const char*` and evaluate at compile time.

Comment: ok now the `size` is redundant. `void foo( char data[size])` is just a different way to write `void foo(char* data)`. You can remove it. `return xxHash64<size>(arr);` doesnt work because function parameters are not constant expressions you cannot use `size` as template argument

Comment: Is `arr_size` actually needed from the hashing function?

Comment: Why are you mucking around with C-style arrays? Just use `std::array` or `std::vector` already.

Answer (score 3):

there is no problem to call `constexpr` function with `constexpr` pointer as constant expression

```
constexpr uint64_t xxHash64(const char* s){return s[0];}
constexpr uint64_t operator "" _g(const char *arr,std::size_t){
    return xxHash64(arr);
}

int main()
{
    xxHash64("foo");
    constexpr auto c = "foobar"_g;
    return c;
}
```

would just work fine.

Comment: I've updated my code and this is indeed correct.
I'm not sure what compiler errors dissuaded me when I tried this, but those were definitely on me.

Answer (score 2):

with c++20, you can also get the size as constant expression with string literal operator template.

```
#include <cstdint>

template <std::size_t arr_size>
constexpr std::uint64_t xxHash64(const char(&data)[arr_size]){
    return data[0];
}

// template <std::size_t N> // can also be full class template (with CTAD)
struct hash_value{
    std::uint64_t value;
    template <std::size_t N>
    constexpr hash_value(const char(&p)[N]):value(xxHash64(p)){}
};


template < hash_value v > 
constexpr std::uint64_t operator ""_hashed() { return v.value; }

int main()
{
    constexpr auto v = "foobar"_hashed;
    return v;
}
```